# How to use navigationController.pushViewController inside nested tableview?

Tags: swift, nested, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a screen with this view hierarchy.

I have tableview inside collectionview, and in that tableview, I have reusable cell.

I want to implement navigationController.pushViewController() when I tap tableview cell which is located in collectinview cell(and of course this  collection view cell is in collectionview).

So I tried to create delegate protocol inside collection view cell which holding tableview.

```
protocol PushViewControllerDelegate {
    func pushViewController() 
}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var delegate: PushViewControllerDelegate?
    var tableView = UITableView()
        
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.pushViewController()
        
    }
}
```

And In the ViewController which hold all of these view hierarchies, wrote like :

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, PushViewControllerDelegate {

    let customCell = CollectionViewCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customCell.delegate = self
    }
    func pushViewController() {
        let vc = SecondVC()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

But this delegate method is not calling when I tap tableview cell.

How can I navigate using pushViewcontroller in my situation?

[image]

Comment: because the `delegate` inside `CollectionViewCell` is `nil`. You have to set it before use it.

Comment: @emrcftci Just edited post. I forgot to write set delegation in this post

Comment: could you please share your `cellForItem` method in `MainViewController`?

Comment: @emrcftci in MainViewController there is collectionview and in cellForItem of this collectionView :             let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ThirdCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            
            return cell

Comment: You can't just create the cell as a property of the `UICollectionViewController` and set the delegate in the `viewDidLoad` function. You have to pass the delegate to the `UICollectionViewCell` when it is created inside the `cellForItem`-function.

BTW to make sure your code does not leak you should make the delegate protocol a `class` protocol and declare it as `weak` in your `UICollectionViewCell`:

`protocol PushViewControllerDelegate: class { ... }`

and inside the cell:

`weak var delegate: PushViewControllerDelegate?`

Comment: @erik_m_martens set delegate inside cellForItem and It works now. Thank you

Comment: because these are two different instances of your cell and you set the delegate of the property one. then you use cell which you're creating an instance in `cellForRow`.

Comment: @emrcftci Yes now I understood.Thank you.

Comment: @erik_m_martens why "class" keyword prevent from memory leak?

Comment: @alphonse to be able to declare a property that is based on a protocol type as weak, you have to make the protocol a class protocol. And you have to declare delegates as weak or you run the risk of creating a retain cycle. Non-weak delegates are a code smell.